NextJS App Router & next-i18n-router, How to get namespaces from nested layouts
I am building an app with NextJS and its app-router. I have set up my app to translate text using this tutorial: https://i18nexus.com/tutorials/nextjs/react-i18next
Everything works except that I'm not sure how to get all the needed namespaces for each route before calling i18nInstance.init().  The main confusion is that I am using nested layouts, and some of these layouts need to be translated.  My app has a route structured like this:
app

[locale]

Layout.tsx (this layout contains UI which requires a namespace called 'common'.)

item

create

Layout.tsx
Page (this page contains UI requiring namespace called 'item'.)









So, for this route ([locale]/item/create/), I would need to initialize i18next with 2 namespaces, ['common', 'item'].
I am initializing i18next from my [locale]/Layout.tsx file like this:
const namespaces = ['common'];

export default async function LocaleLayout({
  children,
  params: {locale}
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: I18nRouterParams;
}) {

  const {resources} = await initTranslations(locale, namespaces);

  return (
    <TranslationsProvider
      locale={locale}
      namespaces={namespaces}
      resources={resources}
    >
      <MainNav>
        {children}
      </MainNav>
    </TranslationsProvider>
  );
}

The initTranslations function looks like this:
export default async function initTranslations(
  locale: string,
  namespaces?: string[],
  i18nInstance?: i18n,
  resources?: Resource,
) {

  i18nInstance = i18nInstance || createInstance();

  i18nInstance.use(initReactI18next);

  if (!resources) {
    i18nInstance.use(
      resourcesToBackend(
        (language: string, namespace: string) =>
          import(`<json_path>/${language}/${namespace}.json`)
      )
    );
  }

  await i18nInstance.init({
    lng: locale,
    resources,
    fallbackLng: i18nConfig.defaultLocale,
    supportedLngs: i18nConfig.locales,
    defaultNS: i18nConfig.defaultNS,
    fallbackNS: i18nConfig.ns[0],
    ns: namespaces || i18nConfig.ns,
    preload: resources ? [] : i18nConfig.locales
  });

  return {
    i18n: i18nInstance,
    resources: i18nInstance.services.resourceStore.data,
    t: i18nInstance.t
  };
}

But somehow I need to know the full route I am on, and add the item namespace to the namespaces argument before I call initTranslations if it's rendering the Page.tsx in my example.
Since this [locale]/Layout.tsx is a server component, I can't use the hooks to get the path (and I don't think Layout files can get the path anyway).  Do I need to do this via middleware? Or do I need something like a class with methods to add namespaces before it initializes? Or have I set this up all wrong?
